# HTML - Will browsers autofill hidden fields?

Tags: html, autocomplete, hidden-fields

My site suffers from a lot of spam bots.  If I have the login form:

```
<input name="username" type="hidden"  />
<input name="password" type="hidden" />

<input name="hidden_1" type="text" />
<input name="hidden_2" type="password" />
```

So the user actually see's the 'hidden' prefix fields, and the username/password named fields are actually the hidden ones.  If the username or password field is submitted with values, we know  bot filled them out and can ban them.

My question is, do browsers auto fill hidden fields?  Is this quite a good technique?  I know this isn't going to stop all bots that are semi intelligent, but if this even blocks 1 bot, without affecting any genuine users it's worth doing.

Comment: I'm using the same technique but some users are reporting failing the bot check, which tells me that the hidden fields were indeed populated.  I can only assume it was due to a browser auto-fill or perhaps some extension they may have enabled on their browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that not all bots just search for "username" and "password" names, but also type="password". So this might not avoid bot access at all.

You can use a capture like [ReCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). It is free and easy to use. Additionally you can create a banlist and show a 404 to bots via htaccess.

Comment: I could have the fake fields type passwords, and offset them off the screen.  If it's in the code before the genuine password field, unsophisticated bots might just fill the first one they come to.

Answer (score 3):

This article might help you:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha/

Your method is actually fairly decent, but you may still suffer from some spam, especially if forms are manually filled out

Comment: Thanks!  But do genuine user browsers auto fill hidden fields is my main question?

Comment: No, unless they have something like the Google add-on for Firefox which autofills forms when you click a button. But even then, I don't think it bothers with hidden fields